# How to set field to null on doctrine migrations using addSql?

Tags: symfony, pdo, doctrine, doctrine-migrations

I'm updating an entity in one of my doctrine migrations with `Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\AbstractMigration::addSql($sql, array $params = array(), array $types = array())`, I have to set up a column as null.

I have already debugged it and I tried to set up the type as `\PDO::PARAM_NULL` but I'm getting the same issue.

SQL:

```
    $sql="INSERT INTO sme_task_template (status_change_final_status) VALUES (:finalStatus)";
    $params=array(
        'finalStatus' => null
    );
    $types=array(
        'finalStatus' => \PDO::PARAM_NULL
    );
    $this->addSql($sql, $params, $types);
```

Exception:

```
  [Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]                                                
  An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO sme_task_template (statu  
  s_change_final_status) VALUES (:finalStatus)' with params [null]:            
  Value for :finalStatus not found in params array. Params array key should b  
  e "finalStatus"
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't get it working with named parameters but it seems to work with question mark parameters.

```
    $sql="INSERT INTO sme_task_template_trigger (status_change_final_status) VALUES (?)";
    $params=array(
        null
    );
    $types=array(
        \PDO::PARAM_NULL
    );
    $this->addSql($sql, $params, $types);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you do that by addSql at all?
AddSQL is mainly for changing schema.
What you need is postUp method and executeQuery.

```php
public function postUp(Schema $schema): void
{
    $this->connection
        ->prepare("UPDATE `my_table` SET `my_field`=:my_value WHERE `other_field` IS NOT NULL")
        ->executeQuery(['my_value' => 'wheee!']);
}
```

Comment: You may be right with your recommendation I do not remember the migration library as I ask that question 8 years ago. Although, the fix to the error was sending a dictionary instead of a list.